# tag names on photo ios

Tags: ios, image, tags, photos

I want to tag names on photos just like in instagram
e.g
before uploading we specify tag name on specific places
[image]

after upload when we click on image the name is displace on that places where we specify. 
[image]

I just want that functionality. The approach which I am thinking that we store x,y position where the tag name appear and embed in the name of image but that approach is not good. any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a database table with he following fields?

```
image_id, /* The image where the tag is in */
person_id, /* The person who is tagged in this image */
x_pos, /* The X Position of the tag */
y_pos /* The Y Position of the tag */
```

If yes, what kind of problems did you run into?